SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I am unable to run selenium tests in Jenkins pipeline because of below error.
Error details -
[Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
12:42:35 (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
12:42:35 (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

SystemInfo -
12:42:35 Host info: host: 'java-11-xlarge-4zcsb', ip: '172.27.227.15'
12:42:35 Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
12:42:35 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.198-187.748.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.16'
12:42:35 Driver info: ChromeDriver
12:42:35 Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-proxy-server, --no-sandbox, --test-type, --window-position=0,0, chrome.switches, ignore-certificate-errors, --remote-allow-origins=*, --disable-dev-shm-usage], binary: /usr/bin/google-chrome, excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], prefs: {credentials_enable_service: false, download.default_directory: /root/workspace/SSK-Test-Pi..., download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.geolocation: 2, profile.default_content_settings.location: 2, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 2}}}]}]

The code runs fine on local windows system. Only on Linux system facing this issue
Even with latest selenium version facing this issue.
4.19.1
Can someone help with this issue? this has been a blocker issue of us as unable to run any regression suites. Really appreciate if we get any help on this.

Can you edit the question and share relevant code?
